# Ubicación de valores repetidos en una lista Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Teniendo una lista:

```
miLista = [2,6,8,5,7,9,6,4,3,6,7,7,5,3,2,5,7,9,7,...]
```

Necesito anexar a otra lista la ubicación de los valores repetidos.

Con un ciclo `for` la puedo recorrer y comparar los números. Pero como obtener la ubicación (indice) de cada elemento repetido (Con `.index()` no puedo porque me devuelve la ubicación del primero encontrado).

Ejemplo quiero obtener la ubicación de todos los 7

```
miLista = [2,6,8,5,7,9,6,4,3,6,7,7,5,3,2,5,7,9,7.......]
ListaUbicaciones = []

for x in miLista:
  if x == 7:
    ListaUbicaciones.append(miLista.index(x))
```

***Nota:** No intento buscar cuales se repiten, ni cuantas veces se repiten.*

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, he probado las 4 respuestas y funcionan perfectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Con `.index()` no puedo porque me devuelve la ubicación del primero encontrado).

Puedes en lugar de iterar sobre cada elemento de lista, iterar sobre cada indice de la lista. Si hay una coincidencia añades el número del indice.

```
for n in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[n] == 7:
        lista_ubicaciones.append(n)
```

Esto también lo puedes reutilizar y reducir en lineas, con una función y una compresión de listas.

```
def get_indexes(ls,index):
    return [i for i in range(len(ls)) if ls[i] == index];
```

Espero te haya ayudado de algo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer una lista por comprehensión que vaya enumerando los elementos y vaya recuperando la enumeración solo de los valores que coincidan con una condición (en este caso, que el valor de la lista sea 7): `ListaUbicaciones = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(miLista) if val == 7]`.

Answer (score 2):

Este código encuentra todos los valores repetidos usando un diccionario (no solo el 7).

El diccionario Ubicaciones está indexado por valor que se repite, y contiene una lista de indices donde se repite el valor.

```
from collections import defaultdict

Ubicaciones = defaultdict(list)
for index in range(len(lista)):
    Ubicaciones[lista[index]].append(index)
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me estaba preguntando como hacer eso =D

Comment: Una consulta. He estado probando el código pero veo que hay claves cuyas listas de indices tienen un solo valor. (si el diccionario Ubicaciones almacena los valores repetidos por que hay claves con una sola ubicación??).

Comment: @Juan. Segui tu ejemplo, que almacena la ubicación de todos los "7" sin importar cuantos hay. Si deseas sólo los autenticos repetidos, descarta el primer valor en cada ubicación.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre algo rápido usando solamente un contador

Declaro una variable que la voy a inicializar en 0, y dentro del `for` le hago el conteo de 1 en 1..

Al momento que consiga el nro asignado, lo que voy a agregar a la listaUbicaciones será el valor de esa variable... Quedaría así:

```
miLista = [7,2,6,8,5,7,9,6,4,3,6,7,7,5,3,2,5,7,9,7]
listaUbicaciones = []
index = 0

for x in miLista:
  if x == 7:
    listaUbicaciones.append(index)
  index += 1

print(miLista)   # solo lo coloqué para ver la lista original y comparar con el resultado
print(listaUbicaciones)
```

No es el resultado más elegante, pero funciona y realiza tu requerimiento.. Fue lo primero que se me vino a la mente.

Verifica y nos comentas

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
miLista = [2, 6, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6, 4, 3, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 9, 7]
listaUbicaciones = []

cuentaRepetidos = {}

for indice, numero in enumerate(miLista):
    
    if numero not in cuentaRepetidos:
        cuentaRepetidos[numero] = 1
        continue

    if cuentaRepetidos[numero] == 1:
        cuentaRepetidos[numero] += 1
        listaUbicaciones.append((numero, indice))

print(listaUbicaciones)
```

Con la ayuda de un diccionario lo que puedes hacer es almacenar los números y las veces que se van repitiendo, en cuanto el número se repite almacenas una tupla en `listaUbicaciones` con el número y el índice en donde lo encontraste.

La función `enumerate` te ayuda a convertir una lista en tuplas de `(indice, numero)` con eso puedes obtener el índice fácilmente.

Adicional a eso en el diccionario `cuentaRepetidos` te quedan almacenados los números y la cantidad de repeticiones de cada uno por si esa información te llega a ser de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

"""
yo tenía el mismo problema, pero despues de mucho ensayo y error este código me funcionó.

miLista = [2,6,8,5,7,9,6,4,3,6,7,7,5,3,2,5,7,9,7.......]
ListaUbicaciones = []

for i, x in enumerate(miLista):
if x == 7:
ListaUbicaciones.append(i)

""""

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente qué hace este código, además de darle el formato correspondiente. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo así:

cont = 0
positions = []
for index, elem in enumerate(numbers):
if elem == number:
cont+=1
positions.append(index)
print(f'El {number} aparece {cont} veces en los indices {positions}')

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente cómo funciona este código, además de darle el formato correspondiente. Lee [answer].