# ¿Cómo encuentro más de un índice en una lista de Python?

Tags: python, lista, indices

Quiero encontrar los índices del elemento con mayor valor

Por ejemplo
Tengo una lista [1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4]

¿Cómo puedo encontrar cuáles son los índices de todos los 4 que aparecen?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ubicación de valores repetidos en una lista Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/378852/ubicaci%c3%b3n-de-valores-repetidos-en-una-lista-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lista=[1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4]
maximo=max(lista)
posiciones = [i for i, x in enumerate(lista) if x == maximo]
print(posiciones)
```

Con `max(lista)` obtienes el mayor elemento. Luego, con List Comprehensions obtienes todas las posiciones en donde se encuentra el elemento.

El resultado de este código es: `[2, 3, 5]`

Comment: ¿Cual será la razón del voto negativo? El código soluciona el problema ...

Comment: No es la primera vez que lo hacen, en ocasiones, si no les gusta la pregunta le quitan votos al usuario que pregunta y a quien responde. Realmente es muy frustrante.

Comment: ¿y dónde queda no responder sin que la pregunta tenga un intento de código?

Comment: Es cierto, pero ese tipo de preguntas a veces son útiles y lo digo por experiencia propia. Además, si la respuesta no es incorrecta por qué afectar a quien responde.